# How could I control the DialogResult of a button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

I want to create a dialog requesting user information, and I set the Ok button's DialogResult to OK. In the OK button's Click event, the program checks for empty textboxes, and if there are empty textboxes, the program shows a message box and stops the dialog box from closing. But because I set the DialogResult to OK, there are no way of stopping the box from closing. Could you give me some solutions? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
outcomeName = outcomeNameTxtBx.Text;
outcomeDetails = outcomeDetailsTxtBx.Text;
addTargetedClasses();
finishDate = finishDatePicker.Value;
beginWorkingDate = beginWorkingDatePicker.Value;

if (!isAllInfoEntered())
{
      //Show the message box
      return;
}
```

Comment: Don't set the DialogResult to OK until *after* you know everything is ok.

Comment: But I want the dialog box to return a DialogResult of OK, is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Setting the DialogResult to anything other than None will close a ShowDialog form.  So if you don't want it to close, don't set it.

Comment: Why not disable the OK button if the textboxes are empty and enable it when all textboxes have content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it back if you are not happy:

```
if (!isAllInfoEntered())
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    //Show the message box
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make return:

```
if (!isAllInfoEntered())
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    //Show the message box
}
else
{
     return;
}
```